# Launch IISExpress with Admin permissions in C#

Tags: .net, iis-express, user-permissions

I need to check if IISexpress is already running in the system or not.. 
If not then I need to start IISExpress with Admin permissions.

To achieve this I am using the following code

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(
                        settings.Default.IISExpressProcessName).ToList();
if (processes.Count != 0) return;
var pass = new SecureString();
foreach (char chr in settings.Default.Password)
{
    pass.AppendChar(chr);
}

var iisExpress = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                         settings.Default.IISExpressExecutableFilePath);
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = iisExpress,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "runas",
    //UserName =settings.Default.UserName,
    //Password = pass, 
    Arguments = settings.Default.IISExpressArguments
});
```

The issue here is that it does not start IISExpress in admin mode.

Can any one help me here?

Comment: Can you take a little bit of care and make sure any code samples pasted into your questions are formatted correctly? Please have a read of: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your code little bit to

```
Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
  {
  FileName = IIS_EXPRESS,
  Arguments = arguments.ToString(),
  RedirectStandardOutput = true,
  UseShellExecute = true,
  CreateNoWindow = true,
  Verb = "runas"
  });
```

this shall do the trick